# Returning flags via source model makes my items inactive (greyed out)

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

In my proxy model with base `QSortFilterProxyModel` in the [flags](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) virtual method:

```
Qt::ItemFlags File_List_Proxy::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if(index.isValid())
    {
        return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | 
            Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable |
            Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    }
    else
    {
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;
    }
}
```

If the function looks like the above (IDENTICAL to model version...just copied and pasted) then items are displayed correctly. But if I change def of this method to use [sourceModel()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractproxymodel.html#sourceModel):

```
Qt::ItemFlags File_List_Proxy::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    return sourceModel()->flags(index);
}
```

...then items on my listView are inactive. Why?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped into the code to confirm that a step-in on the `sourceModel()->flags(index)` lands you in an identical routine?

Comment: Yes, it goes into the the right function.

Comment: Well how about write your flags function as doing it *both* ways...so you fetch the Qt::ItemFlags from calling sourceModel, and then provide a place where you break if it doesn't equal the result of the same calculation?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you map the index to source model index ?

```
Qt::ItemFlags File_List_Proxy::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    return sourceModel()->flags(this->mapToSource(index));
}
```

Because to my point of view the index is not related to the same model, so it's invalid

Comment: Yeah this is most likely the problem, `index` is part of the proxy model; the source model will not know that index unless you map it.

Comment: @totem nope, it's still the same.